# File Upload Preview in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

How can I implement file upload preview(http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/). I am using the this file upload. https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

If i add this preview script, angular script is not working in my page.

Here is my controller structure.

```
var app = angular.module('nomunoli.controllers', []);

app.controller('NMNL012Ctrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'NMNL012Service', '$location', 
   function ($scope, $routeParams, NMNL012Service, $location) {

            var request = {'groupId': $routeParams.id};
            $scope.group = NMNL012Service.nmnl012FUN14.query(request);
            $scope.talentList = NMNL012Service.nmnl012FUN01.query(request);

        }]
    );
```

This is input div in page.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="talentUpload" type="file" ng-file-select ng-model="talentFile" accept="image/*" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker??

Comment: I have not used plunker before. I will try to provide.

Comment: Please provide more of your code to find the problem